# How to programatically build an xml with soap in c# with xmlns:soap12, xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, xsd, xml-namespaces

I need to programatically created a xml that looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Profile xmlns="http://google.com">
      <number>123</number>
      <name>bob</name>
    </Profile>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Currently it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <Profile xmlns="http://google.com">
      <number>123</number>
      <name>bob</name>
    </Profile>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The code I have so far is:

```
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Users\Default\Desktop\books.xml"))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("soap12", "Envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
                writer.WriteStartElement("soap12", "Body", null);
                writer.WriteStartElement("Profile", "http://google.com");

                writer.WriteElementString("number", "123");
                writer.WriteElementString("name", "bob");

            }
```

Can someone please help me with this one?

Thank you!

Comment: Sequential order of the namespaces is irrelevant.

Comment: Right, but I only have one namespace vs the one I want it to look like which has three. @YitzhakKhabinsky

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                          "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"" +
                             " xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                             " xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                          "</soap12:Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement envelope = doc.Root;
            XNamespace soap12Ns = envelope.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("soap12");


            XElement body = new XElement(soap12Ns + "Body");
            envelope.Add(body);

            XNamespace ns = "http/://google.com";
            XElement profile = new XElement(ns + "Profile");
            body.Add(profile);

            profile.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement(ns + "number", 123),
                new XElement(ns + "name", "bob")
            });



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jdweng, however, the output is one namespace, not all three. Can you help me with that? Still gives me same output as I was getting with the code I provided.

Comment: what is in the first line of the xml doesn't matter as long as the namespace is defined before it is used.  To have unused should not cause any issues.  I matched what you had posted.  If you need different namespaces then get more using envelope.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("XYZ");